# Determining where the Markup Extension is being called from during design time

Tags: c#, wpf, design-time, markup-extensions

In the `ProvideValue`  method of my Markup Extension: I would like to know the name of the file (or the class of the user control) which uses my Markup Extension during design time.

Is this possible somehow?

Comment: Why are you wanting to know?

Comment: One option that *might* work is to examine `Environment.StackTrace` inside `ProvideValue` and use a regex to extract any file names or project-local type-names, then output it using `Debug.WriteLine`.

Comment: Dai - I have some translated text stored in csv files. These csv files have the same name as the view. I want the translations to also appear during design time.

Comment: Why not use a proper localization XAML extension instead?